# Restoring CheckBox state in an ArrayList never sets CheckBoxes as checked

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-checkbox

I'm attempting to restore a list of checkboxes's 'ischecked' state however the boxes are never checked for some reason.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something small.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

### Source:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile_notification_settings_list_new_message);
        pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        final int selection = pref.getInt("ChatRepeatPosition", 0);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Repeat Notification In");
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);
        dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.repeat,
                R.id.repeat_tv, text);
        list.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);

        if (list != null && selection != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
                cb.setId(i);
                if (i == selection) {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                } else {

                    CheckBox cbb = new CheckBox(this);
                    cbb.setChecked(false);
                }

            }

        }
```

Full Source:

https://pastebin.com/tAMTam3X

### Edit:

The first 'answer' shown below is not what I'm attempting on accomplish. I fully understand how to restore the state of a single checkbox. I'm having trouble iterating through my list of checkboxes to restore the state of all of them (I am able to iterate through the list in list.setOnItemClickListener because I can get the view - but I'm not sure how to iterate through the list in oncreate)

[checkbox list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8COY.png)

Comment: what does this part of your code do ?
 if (list != null && selection != 0) {
           ....
   }
please put all your codes here in different code blocks.
and explain more about the problem

Comment: Have you verified the value of selection >0

Comment: @Psypher - Yes - I have - that is not the issue

Comment: Also - I edited the question for additional clarity - perhaps I wasn't clear in exactly what I'm attempting to accomplish the first time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're creating new `CheckBox` objects and not doing anything with them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {        
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
    cb.setId(i);

    if (i == selection) {
        cb.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        CheckBox cbb = new CheckBox(this);
        cbb.setChecked(false);
    }
}
```

This loops through the size of the list, initializes `CheckBox`s, sets the checked state on those `CheckBox`s and then ... well, that's it. They are in no way associated with the `ListView`, so how would its state get updated?

What you want to do is use the [setItemChecked](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked(int,%20boolean)) method, something like this:

```
final int selection = pref.getInt("ChatRepeatPosition", 0);
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.simpleListView);
list.setItemChecked(selection, true);
```

And you can delete the for loop that literally does nothing.

If you want to read more than one saved selection, then you would need to read from a database or file since preferences are limited to key / value pairs. But the concept would be the same: read the list of selections, iterated through the list, set the item checked on the list view.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

try this.. in the on create add your checkbox and initialize it.

```
cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yourxmlid);
```

then add a shared pref to check the state of the check box

```
 sharedpreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    boolean checkedFlag1 = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("checkboxstate", false);
    cb1.setChecked(checkedFlag1);
```

then finally in your onCheckListener add a shared pref to check the box

```
 cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (cb1.isChecked()) {

                editor.putBoolean("checkboxstate", true);
                editor.commit();


                Log.i("Checkbox ", "Activated");

            }else{

                editor.putBoolean("checkboxstate", false);
                editor.commit();
                Log.i("Checkbox: ","Deactivated");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: this seems like it would restore the state for one checkbox - which is not what I'm trying to do - I'm trying to restore the state of all the checkboxes in my list as shown here: 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPv8c.png